# How to set RGB value in Python?

Tags: python

```
import turtle as t
t.Screen().bgcolor('#8A360F')
```

For above scripts, is there a way that I can set `RGB(138, 54, 15)` instead of `'#8A360F'`?

e.g.

```
t.Screen().bgcolor(RGB(138, 54, 15))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use the :x operator and make a custom formula

```
def rgb_to_hex(r, g, b):
      return ('{:X}{:X}{:X}'). format(r, g, b)
```

Now call this within the bgcolor function,
It works because :x makes normal values become hex values

```
import turtle as t
t.Screen().bgcolor(rgb_to_hex(100, 120, 90))
```

Comment: Got error message. It shows 'turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color string: 64785A'

Comment: This answer is *almost* complete, but needs a few improvements. Change the string to `'#{:02X}{:02X}{:02X}'`. A color needs to start with `#`, and each color component should have two digits with single-digit numbers starting with `0`.

Comment: Great, now it works well. I found another to do it through `colormode()`. 
`import turtle as t 
t.Screen().colormode(255) 
t.Screen().bgcolor(100, 120, 90)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this way

```
import turtle as t
t.pencolor(83, 58, 27)
```

Comment: got error message: turtle.TurtleGraphicsError: bad color sequence: (83, 58, 27)